# Running NextFlow pipeline in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, pipeline, nextflow

I created a NextFlow pipeline to analyze RNA sequences, I want to run the pipeline on mupltiple samples. I have multiple servers which I can utilise for the task.

I'm wondering if it makes sense to run Nextflow pipelines through Jenkins to manage the distribution of tasks in multiple servers?

I couldn't find any information on combining Jenkins and Nextflow.

I've tried to look and stackoverflow, Jenkins, and NextFlow fourms to undersand if I can combine both tools. However, I couldn't find any answers.